Create Outlook/Exchange calendar with ASP CLASSIC
inside an OLD application written using ASP CLASSIC, I need to implement Outlook invitation/calendar.
First of all, my routine creates the .ICS file (and I put into "Modello_Invito" variable the same content) and I save .ICS file a flat-text file
    BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 9.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Rome
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
TZNAME:CEST
DTSTART:20241109T103600Z
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
TZNAME:CET
DTSTART:20241109T103600Z
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20241108T000000Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20241108T000000Z
DTSTAMP:20241108T180800Z
UID:{9A7BC596-7C70-4329-9425-52486FC83D85} i
SUMMARY:Calendar: OGGETTO
ORGANIZER;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:mailto:sender@mailserver.com
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:mailto:receiver@mailserver.com
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Rome:09/11/2024T12:36
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Rome:09/11/2024T17:36
PRIORITY:3
TRANSP:OPAQUE
LOCATION:LUOGO MEETING
DESCRIPTION;ALTREP:Proviamo
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:PT30M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

and after that, I try to send this invitation to the invited user
    Dim objMail
Set objMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
  objMail.From = eMail_Sender
  objMail.To = eMail_Dest
  objMail.Cc = ""
  objMail.Bcc = ""
  objMail.Subject = trim(Obj_Calendar)

  objMail.BodyPart.ContentMediaType = "text/calendar" 
  objMail.BodyPart.Charset = "UTF-8" 
  objMail.HTMLBody = Modello_Invito
  objMail.AddAttachment sICS_file

I put .ICS content both into attachment and into Body of email.
The email arrives with .ICS file as attachement but the email client not recognize that it's a calendar.
Reading feedbacks from other users in other posts, I added in my code "content-type" suggested:
  objMail.Fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:content-class") = "urn:content-classes:calendarmessage" 
  objMail.Fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:content-type") = "text/calendar; method=REQUEST; charset=UTF-8"
  objMail.Fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:content-transfer-encoding") = "8bit" 

but the result is not as desired.
An email arrives with the .ICS file attached, the Content-Type is correctly set to “text/calendar” but the mail client does not recognize that it is a calendar invitation.
So the buttons Accept, Reject and To confirm are not displayed.
Any suggestions?

To be recognized as an invitation, your message must contain a single part (ICS). The message content-type must text/calendar. Do not add any MIME parts, the message must only contain the payload:
Content-Type: text/calendar; method=REQUEST; charset=UTF-8
Subject: Test
From: test@example.demo
To: someuser@example.demo

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 9.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Rome
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
TZNAME:CEST
DTSTART:20241109T103600Z
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
TZNAME:CET
DTSTART:20241109T103600Z
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20241108T000000Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20241108T000000Z
DTSTAMP:20241108T180800Z
UID:{9A7BC596-7C70-4329-9425-52486FC83D85} i
SUMMARY:Calendar: OGGETTO
ORGANIZER;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:mailto:sender@mailserver.com
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:mailto:receiver@mailserver.com
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Rome:09/11/2024T12:36
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Rome:09/11/2024T17:36
PRIORITY:3
TRANSP:OPAQUE
LOCATION:LUOGO MEETING
DESCRIPTION;ALTREP:Proviamo
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:PT30M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR


Thank you @Dmitry. Content-type is already set as "text/calendar" (as you can see) and my message contains ICS text (both as e-mail body and attachment)

It has to be set on the main (message) part, not one of the parts. If you have any attachments, they must be included as part of the ICS data. There shouldn't be any MIME parts besides the outer message itself

Do you have the code? Could you share it? So we can better understand the solution to the problem

See the updated answer above - that is how the whole message should look like.

Using my code, when invitation arrives, has
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/calendar;
method=REQUEST;
charset="UTF-8"
Content-Class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage    but email client non identify the message as an invitation

Can you post the full MIME source?

All ASP code is inside my question (above). It's missing only .send command.  What can I add more? Or, in your opinion, what is missing?

I can only assume what that code creates. Try to send the request to a Gmail address - you can then view the message source in the Gmail mailbox. Even then, your code sets body part and adds attachments separately. There is no way the message will have no MIME parts other than the root message. It is guaranteed to be a multipart message.


Thread-Topic: SUBJECT OF INVITATION
From: sender
To: receiver
Cc: 
Subject: SUBJECT OF INVITATION
Date: Thu, 14 Nov 2024 20:20:13 +0100
Message-ID: <700FA8CC327@server.it>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/calendar;
 method=REQUEST;
 charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage
X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE
X-CMAE-Envelope: MS4xfIIRF+mc/85tP5j0CFNYkvWxKywvHXOw6DoQsjxnm2WvcZeaZvyvNzt7MQb5urS19P

Here full result:     https://t.ly/DqXk5

That looks fine. If I save that an an EML file and double click on it from Windows Explorer, Outlook opens it as a meeting invitation, albeit with disabled Accept/Reject buttons "(as the meeting organizer, you don't need to respond")

Thank you @Dmitry for our feedback. So file is correct but when I send via email, the recepient client  does not interpret this message as an invitation. I also find that in my source-code that I put {content-transfer-encoding = 8bit} but into result email you can see "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit". I don't know if his can have effects

Try to send a meeting invitation from Outlook to a gmail mailbox, look at its source to see what is different.

In fact...the body of the invitation I read just by analyzing the incoming message from both Outlook invitations and invitations generated by other clients. But this is the "final result" of invitation. I think that «something» is missing/wrong into ASP code :-/ but not understand what.... also because, as you wrote, if you take the generated text and save it as an .EML file, the invitation is interpreted correctly. The invitation code is the same for Outlook, Thunderbird, GMail, ....

So what do you see in a Gmail mailbox for invitation generated by your code and generated by Outlook? Have you tried to compare the MIME source?

Code generated is the same. In my opinion the "error" is into message sent using "CDO.Message" object. Some parameter. For example, in my source-code that I put {content-transfer-encoding = 8bit} but into result email you can see "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit"

Can you post both good and bad MIME messages?

The code that I use is written above. With and without "AddAttachment" (it seems that no attachment is needed). I put this code online: https://queccu2.bsite.net/Invitation.asp

I don't mean the code. I mean the resulting MIME message source. You can see it in Gmail if you click "..." | "Show Original".
Your site will not let me send anything - it returns "Mittente non consentito / Sender not allowed ( mail from )"
